# Any help recognising a handwritten kanji?

Tags: kanji, handwriting

I've recently gotten into translating fancomics for a manga, although I'm still a beginner at Japanese. Naturally, I don't really know my kanji and I have to rely on a lot of looking up radical and kanji lists or using OCR (the few times it works).
In one of those fancomics, I've encountered a kanji that I've been unable to recognise successfully for a few days now.
Here's a pic of the kanji in question.

[image]

If I'm not mistaken the top-left radical is 广 and I tried to search based on that (as well as other similar radicals in case I *am* mistaken). I also tried to look based on the furigana at the left (or at least I think it's furigana) that based on other instances of the artist's handwriting, I took to be に. However, with either of those methods I couldn't find any kanji that seemed to fit the image well enough nor any that seemed to make any sense meaning-wise (though I will admit I could have been missing something as my Japanese is beginner level, after all).
For the context of where the kanji appeared, I have this:

告白する相手を間違えてませんか ("Haven't you made a mistake about whom to confess to?" as per my translation)
(?)では
ないですね
The two latter lines are different speech bubbles, but I suspect they might be a single sentence.

If someone can recognise the kanji, I'd grateful for the help, but I'd also appreciate tips on how I might go about this kind of research more efficiently myself. After all, it's very possible I'll come up this problem again in the future and I can't always rely on others.

In any case, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It's 嘘, though I think this kind of question is considered off topic.

Comment: @Leebo I don't see anything off-topic about this, it shows very clear research effort and an earnest willingness to learn more.

Comment: @droooze I wasn't suggesting it wasn't written earnestly, but "methods for how to recognize characters" is generally considered a meta topic at least, isn't it.

Comment: I have a feeling someone will mention a handwriting app. I must say, if one isn't familiar with the character components, a handwriting app won't really help pick the right character - it'll just bring up a list of choices which narrows down the guesswork.

Comment: @Leebo Thanks you very much for your help and for the quick reply. I looked up a few similar questions before making mine and I noticed that the ones marked as off-topic had the following reason given: "Questions asking for translations, transcriptions or proofreading are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated". I figured that as such mine wouldn't be off-topic, but hey I'm new here, could be wrong.

Comment: For future visitor since you might be a expert in Japanese already. https://jisho.org/search/one%20thing#handwriting it's great tool you can find your Kanji by drawing also or search using Romaji if you know how to read it.

Answer (score 3):

The character is「嘘」.

<sub>Assuming that you've identified the *furigana* correctly, I can't think of a word where「嘘」has a reading「に」. However, I also think that *furigana* are usually written on the right, not on the left as specified in the question.</sub>

---

I guess this is a question of character decomposition:

- 「嘘{きょ・こ}」is made from

  - Semantic「口」(*mouth*, referring to some action by the mouth)
  - Phonetic「虚{きょ・こ}」(referring to the *on'yomi*), which is made from

    - **Phonetic「虍{こ}」** (not「广」). As reinforcement,「虍{こ}」is also the phonetic of 「虎{こ}」.
    - Semantic「丘」(*large hill mound*), now appearing as「业」inside the character「虚」in Japanese *Shinjitai*.「虚」originally meant *large mound*, but this is not relevant to the modern meaning.

Comment: FYI: Character components should generally not be called *radicals*. Radicals are dictionary section headers, and don't specify what characters are actually composed from.

Comment: Ah yes thanks. I think I mistook the mouth component as the furigana (well I wasn't entirely certain one way or another, it was just a hypothesis). And thanks for the note on the radicals.  Will keep that in mind.

Comment: @FigrothFelanor oh, right, now that I look at it I can see why you saw that as「に」.